# Is it correct to add event to Bloc in initState or didUpdateWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc

Is it correct to add event to Bloc in initState or  didChangeDependencies?

I tried to add event in initState and didChangeDependencies. But throw this exception.

But when this page opens again, everything work fine.

```bash
The following StateError was thrown building BlocBuilder<SlotsBloc, SlotsState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<SlotsBloc?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<SlotsBloc, SlotsState>#29045):
Bad state: No element
```

Comment: Can you include sample snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is how Bloc is intended to be used.

By reading a lot of examples on the [official documentation](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples), i see that the `BlocProviders` are always placed somewhere within the widget tree.
This means that they are not accessible without a `BuildContext`, so you can't access them in `initState` or in `didChangeDependencies`.

Another problem with this approach is that you are letting the user interface dictate state changes, and it should be the opposite.

Comment: I need to trigger an event when I enter the page. Is it correct to add the event where I navigate to this page?

Comment: Yes, that's definitely cleaner than overriding `initState`

Answer (score 0):

you can do sth like this:

```
BlocProvider<SlotsBloc>(
      create: (context) => SlotsBloc()..add(SlotInitState()),
      child: child
)
```

Comment: I add the event after doing some checks. And I'm wrapping it with a bloc provider from the top of the MaterialApp. I guess I can't add events here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem calling in `initState`, it all depends on what you need.
See in the example that I instantiated the bloc inside the statefull, called an event and passed it to `BlocBuilder`, with this you can use the bloc instance to add other events without having to read the context and at the same time I provide it to BlocBuilder, if you don't pass the bloc to BlocBuilder it will do the same thing you did in initState, run a `BlocProvider.of<ExampleBloc>(context)` to access the instance in context.

Observer this official example from the documentation, [github_Search](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/github_search/flutter_github_search/lib/search_form.dart).

```
class MyHomeStatefull extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomeStatefull({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomeStatefull> createState() => _MyHomeStatefullState();
}

class _MyHomeStatefullState extends State<MyHomeStatefull> {
  late ExampleBloc exampleBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    // instance bloc and insert event
    exampleBloc = BlocProvider.of<ExampleBloc>(context)..add(StartEvent());

    //or

    //exampleBloc = context.read<ExampleBloc>()..add(StartEvent());
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Page')),
      body: BlocBuilder<ExampleBloc, ExampleState>(
        bloc: exampleBloc,
        builder: (context, state) {
          if (state.isLoading) {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
          return ListView(
            children: List.generate(
              state.listInterger.length,
              (index) => ListTile(
                title: Text('${state.listInterger[index]}'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          exampleBloc.add(OtherEvent());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```